# Metropolis-Hastings not clearly understood

Tags: markov-chains, monte-carlo

I am trying to understand how the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm works and, if possible, to build a small example myself (to be sure that I have understood correctly).

Unfortunately, there are still a number of points that bother me in constructing this algorithm.…

For example, in the various explanations that I encounter here or there, it is explained that we want to construct a chain $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ with $n$ states whose equilibrium vector is given by a certain vector $(\pi_1, …, \pi_n)$ given in advance (so-called “target distribution”).

Okay. But it’s not indicated if $\pi_i >0, \ \forall i$ or if some elements can be zero... (although I don't see why it could be possible...). Are we actually imposing $\pi_i >0, \ \forall i$? **-> [question 1]**

We then give ourselves a proposition matrix (generally named $Q$, so-called “transition kernel”), for which it is generally required that it be irreducible, aperiodic and that $q_{i,j}>0 \Longrightarrow q_{j,i}>0 $. But these conditions are not always indicated…. Why are the characteristics of $Q$ not always fully explained? **-> [question 2]**

Then, we suppose that the chain $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ that we want to build is (at a certain time $t$) in the state $X_t =i$, and we propose a next state $X_{t+1}=j$    by first calculating the so-called “acceptance probabilities”:

$$a_{i,j}=\min\left(1, \frac{\pi_j q_{j,i}} {\pi_i q_{i,j}}\right), \forall j \ 1 <= j <= n $$

Then, we say that we accept $j$ with the probability $a_{i,j}$ and that, otherwise, we stay on $X_{t+1}=X_t=i$.

OK, but this raises some other questions:

When we calculate the $ a_{i,j}$, why can't we have $ q_{i,j}=0$? **-> [question 3]**

If several $ a_{i,j}$ are equal to $1$, how do we make a choice? **-> [question 4]**

It seems that we must accept $j=1$ with probability $a_{i,1}$, but also $j=2$ with probability $a_{i,2}$, etc. How is it possible ? **-> [question 5]**

That's a lot of questions about a Metropolis-Hastings approach, but I couldn't find any clear document. Do you know where I could find the answers to these questions to help me progress in understanding the algorithm?

Comment: Speaking only for myself, the best explanation of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm I have found is that given in the book *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis* by John R. Kruschke.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to have $\pi_i>0$ for all $i$, technically. But there is no good reason to spend resources on bookkeeping for a state that you want your chain to never visit. Also, if you define $a_{i,j}$ in your program by an actual division as you described in #3, then having any $\pi_i=0$ will cause a technical problem due to division by zero. If you insist on including such a state in your setup, then this technical problem can be circumvented. Post a comment if you would like me to expand on this technicality.
2. Irreducibility of the proposal chain is necessary, that should really be asserted or at least be extremely obvious from how it is assembled. Aperiodicity of the proposal chain is *not* necessary, as aperiodicity of the full M-H chain will happen as long as proposal rejections ever occur, i.e. as long as the proposal chain is not already reversible wrt $\pi$.
3. $q_{i,j}=0$ will never come up because given the previous state $i$, you produce $j$ by drawing a sample from the distribution of $q_{i,j}$ to begin with. (There is a slight mathematical subtlety about the distinction between "probability zero" and "impossible" going on here. Post a comment if you would like me to expand on this.)
4. You accept the move to $j$, which at this point has already been proposed, with probability $a_{i,j}$. There is no issue with having multiple $j$ such that $a_{i,j}=1$ (this just means that there are several transitions from $i$ that you are guaranteed to accept).
5. Again the $a_{i,j}$ are just the acceptance probabilities, which only come up after the proposal to move to $j$ has already been made. The overall transition probability in the full M-H chain is $a_{i,j} q_{i,j}$. Analytically speaking, it is easier to think about M-H that way, i.e. as "a Markov chain with transition probabilities given by $a_{i,j} q_{i,j}$ for $j \neq i$, where $\pi_i$ and $q_{i,j}$ are given and $a_{i,j}$ is computed using this formula". (This observation is actually important in that it verifies that the full M-H chain is actually Markov, which is not entirely obvious from the way it is normally described.)

Comment: Thank you for your long detailed reply. Please consider the followings: 
Point 1 – Understood 
Point 2 - Do you mean that, if we start from $i$ and all the $j$ $(1<=j<=n)$ are rejected, then we have to stay in $i$ and therefore we loop on $i$ which becomes aperiodic, as well as the whole chain...? But what guarantees that for a certain $i$, all $j$ are rejected? 
Point 3 – Not quite clear… What prevents me from proposing a matrix $Q$ for which a certain $q_{i,j}=0$, if it is not defined in advance as unacceptable ?

Comment: Point 4 - You mean that, since $j$ goes through all the states from $1$ to $n$, as soon as a certain $a_{I,j}$ is equal to $1$, the corresponding state $j$ is accepted (and it does not matter if other $a_{I,j}$ are also equal to $1$ for other $j’s$…)?

Comment: Point 5 –The process of selecting the next state is still unclear ; say we start from $X_t=1$ and we compute $a_{1,2}$, $a_{1,3}$,…,$a_{1,n}$, according to the formula, for accepting or rejecting $j=2$, $j=3$,…,$j=n$, as the next state. Say we first have $a_{1,2}=1/2$; do we accept $j=2$ as $X_{t+1}$ with probability $1/2$ and reject $j=2$ as $X_{t+1}$ with probability $1/2$ ? Correct ?

Comment: Now suppose we accept $j=2$; in that case, do we discard the following $a_{1,2}$ and so on, as we already know that $X_{t+1}=2$ ?

But what if $a_{1,3}=1$ ???

Or, suppose we reject $j=2$; in that case, do we have to stay on state 1 ?

But what if $a_{1,3}=1$ ???

Comment: @Andrew To understand point 2 you should be considering the point that the full M-H chain has transition probabilities $a_{i,j} q_{i,j}$ for $j \neq i$ and a transition probability from $i$ to $i$ of $1-\sum_{j \neq i} a_{i,j} q_{i,j}$. As long as that transition from $i$ to $i$ has positive probability for some $i$ and the proposal chain is irreducible, then the M-H chain is aperiodic, even if the proposal chain is not (because for any $j,k$ there is a path from $j$ to $k$ through $i$ using the self-loop zero times and another path that is identical except that it uses the self-loop one time.

Comment: @Andrew In point 3, there is no problem in having some $q_{i,j}=0$, but if this occurs then when starting at $i$, such a $j$ will be proposed only with probability zero. Moreover because we control that part of the implementation, we can choose that such a $j$ is surely never generated, rather than only almost surely never generated.

Comment: @Andrew In point 4 and 5 you pick a $j$ using the proposal chain and then the M-H chain either moves to $j$ with probability $a_{i,j}$ or stays at $i$ with probability $1-a_{i,j}$. Since $j$ had probability $q_{i,j}$ to be selected in the first place and the randomization of the acceptance is independent of the randomization that chose $j$, you get the overall property of the M-H chain that I described in the answer and in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain. It's becoming clearer. Can I abuse regarding point 3: could you elaborate on your statement "we can choose that such a j is surely never generated, rather than only almost surely never generated"...? If some $q_{i,j}=0$, what would be the difference between "surely never generated" and "almost surely never generated"? Is not the result simply "never generated"? And in MH, is it allowed to have a state from the proposal distribution never generated? And, if it is allowed ($q_{i,j}=0$), wouldn't that be stupid?

Comment: @Andrew In point 3, the question is: if you know that there is probability zero that a transition from $i$ to $j$ will be proposed, will it ever be proposed (in other words, do you need error handling for the division by zero that would result if it were proposed)? Mathematically the answer is "maybe", but because you're the one writing the code for the proposal chain, you can make the answer be "no".

Comment: @Andrew As for the question about stupidity, it would be stupid to have a $j$ with $q_{i,j}=0$ for all $i$, but it is extremely common to have pairs $(i,j)$ with $q_{i,j}=0$. For example in the Ising model one proposal chain is described by "flip a single spin uniformly at random", in which case the overwhelming majority of the $q_{i,j}$ are zero.

Comment: $@$ Ian, in case $q_{i,j}=0$ (which implies that $q_{j,i}=0$), one could set $\frac{\pi_j \times q_{j,i}}{\pi_i \times q_{i,j}}=0$, so that $a_{i,j}=0$, meaning that if you start on state $i$ and propose such a $j$, it will never be accepted, and so you stay on $i$. (I don't know if some rules are applied in that case, but it seems to make sense). By the way, thanks for reminding me the Ising model.

Comment: @Andrew My point is that you don't even need to do the case work for this "0/0=0" acceptance; you can ensure that the $j$ you propose will never have $q_{i,j}=0$, and thus never have to worry about a division by zero, as long as $\pi_i>0$ for all $i$. (And as I said in point 1, if that isn't the case, then you can just delete states until it is.)